# Subquery with Select Top inside and Order DESC outside of it and still get the last data of the table [Bug]?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I'm Having a weird day about sub query with selecting top inside and having it in order outside of it and still getting the very buttom of the list, I have 100+ rows fyi, please help.

```
DECLARE @FullName VARCHAR(500) = (
    SELECT TOP 1 * 
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT TOP (5) A.RequestID
        FROM [dbo].[Registration] AS [A] 
        LEFT JOIN [dbo].[StuInfo] AS [B] ON A.EmpUsername = B.KIusername 
        WHERE Reason = 'DROP' 
            AND DATEDIFF(day, DateAdded, getdate()) > 25
            AND DATEDIFF(day, DateAdded, GETDATE()) < 31
    ) DB
    ORDER BY RequestID DESC
)
SELECT @FullName
```

Comment: The `TOP 5` in the inner query has no meaning, because there is no order for the inner query. The database is free to pick any five rows it wants for that part.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn it work! I just add an order inside with same logic outside! thank you very much! do you want to write the answer or not?

Comment: Why have you got this nested `TOP` arrangement anyway? If you are trying to get the fifth row just use `ORDER BY RequestID  OFFSET 4 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY`

Comment: @MartinSmith
It's because i'm trying to mimic the whileif decrementation on C#.
it's something like this on C# ----------------while if(A < B, i ){ Execute Insert, i - 1 }
else { Done }

Comment: No that still makes no sense, you should be able to do that with either `OFFSET` or window functions. And rather than doing functions on columns (which means you cannot use indexes) calculate your start and end dates `AND DateAdded > DATEADD(day, 25, getdate()) AND DateAdded < DATEADD(day, 31, getdate())`